# How to log every executed line of code in Java for debug purposes

Tags: java, bytecode

I am using a third party open source library for authentication in my web app.  Its logging is lacking to say the least.  I do have the code (its on github) and can find choice locations in the code to log but I was wondering if there is a quick way to alter the byte-code to log each line of code?  Similar to Jacoco or Clover, except its for logging and not code coverage.  I assumed there would have been a top search result for this on Google or Stackoverflow but maybe I am not using the right search query.

So far I took the code from github and created an uber jar of it using Shades Maven plugin.  So all the code byte code, and its dependencies are in one jar file.

EDIT:  To answer the question of why I would want to do this.  The library has a lot of classes.  Essentially its very time consuming to find where the problem could be.  And while I am wasting time typing this question and can be finding the best places to log, I want the answer because if I come across this in the future I would like to use this same approach.  If I add the logging manually, I would have to compile, and deploy, then when I see that I logged the wrong lines or now need to log more lines, then I would rinse/repeat till I hunt down the culprit.  This is more than just solving this immediate problem, this is something that should be doable within Java's various tools and I want to know how to do it, so please keep answers related to solving my question and not providing workarounds.

Comment: Not sure why you would want this? Wouldn't it be better to single-step through in debug mode - in particular since the source code is available to you?

Comment: Have you tried using log4j? It provides a very thorough logging mechanism.

Comment: You might be entering in to a world of pain, but here's my 50p - write an agent to do it!! https://chimpler.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/implementing-a-java-agent-to-instrument-code/

Comment: You could also use AOP and intercept every method call.

Comment: @ajan yes AOP is what I had in mind.

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup, I editted question to answer your question.

Comment: I would go with @Ajan's suggestion. Put an aspect on all methods in the relevant packages to find the hotspot and then single-step debug from there.

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup thanks, will follow that lead.

Comment: If you really want to do this I'd suggest trying http://byteman.jboss.org/. It's very good for tracing code without having to recompile.

Comment: @mikea thanks.  reading up on it.

Comment: Agree with @AndersR.Bystrup, this is what step-through debugging is for.

Comment: Use a profiler to narrow the code that actually gets executed before placing log statements or setting break points. I’m quite sure that you *don’t* want *every* line to become logged…

Comment: For method-based logging, have a look at https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy and the agent builder, it provides. I once used logging as a use case: http://mydailyjava.blogspot.no/2015/01/make-agents-not-frameworks.html?m=1